# How companies like UDEMY protects videos from being downloaded

Tags: security, video-streaming, html5-video

> **DISCLAIMER** :) :)
>
> Some of them may think it's not relevant for discussion as it does not
>   fit here. Why not? As I think in StackOverflow we find smartest people
>   around the globe. Even if I try to create in other StackOverflow
>   domains it won't be that visible.
>
> **NOTE:** So if your the kind of guy who is trying to pull this down. Please
>   have some pity on me as I won't get good answers in other Q&A sites
>   like Quora

I would like to understand how companies like UDEMY protects the videos that are not allowed to download. I know they cant just fully protect but can harden it via various methods. Some of them what I found is as follows:

```
In Udemy I saw with point 3. Sounds interesting.
```

Starting from basic one

```
1. Disable right-click to download (Can be hacked by disabling the browser js). 

2. You can use custom video libraries or no download options but god knows how fairly it plays. As I was able to download that kind of video.

3. Using BLOB URL for the video, this downloads the video in bytes. (Kind of secure using but can use HLS video downloader)

4. Can use On-demand live HTTP video streaming from Amazon or Vimeo but over time they may cost much price.

5. Then I read about large giants like Netflix, Amazon Prime uses multiple streaming files which will be stored in different chucks. Which makes it harder to download.
```

Any other ways you guys might have found an interesting way to harden it would love to hear.

**AT THE END OF THE DAY USER CAN STILL SCREEN RECORD YOUR VIDEOS DAMMMMMM IT!**

Comment: They are simple protections. Video capture from the screen beats all.

Comment: @kelalaka Ya totally agree with you. Just to impress the clients I want to know more. They are not understanding even if I explain them. They get really impressed with hearing cool names and implementations whether it's secure or not. Dealing with a totally bunch of idiots.

Comment: Also, shift+right click solves the right click problem, at least in my browser. Streaming with limited buffer and a fragmented buffer is also used.

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: DRM - PlayReady, Widevine, etc

Answer (score 4):

Streaming IS downloading. If you want someone to be able to watch a video, you MUST let them download it.

The way large sites protect the content is not through downloading, but by encrypting the files BEFORE they are downloaded. Then the player knows how it request the decryption key from a DRM server.

For more information, read about DRM and EME on Wikipedia.

Comment: That's a really good start for me. Thanks for the showing the path. +1